# How to send data from a background thread created by one activity to another activity that is known to be active?

Tags: android, static, background, thread-safety, real-time

First, I should be clear by providing a little background: I'm using Eclipse to develop an Android application that plots Bluetooth data. It consists primarily of a Bluetooth Activity, a background thread created by the Bluetooth Activity, and a Plotting Activity.

The primary focus of my question: Once the Plotting Activity is known to be active, what approach can I use to send BluetoothData from the background thread to the Plotting Activity so I can plot it?

This is open source code that I am hacking. Using Logcat I know for a fact that the Bluetooth Activity created a background thread for continually producing BluetoothData even after the Bluetooth Activity is gone. And I have found the background method that logs the BluetoothData to Logcat. Now I want to leverage this method to send BluetoothData to the active Plotting Activity so I can plot it.

I can tell you what appears to work. Interested? Define a static method, plotData(BluetoothData) in the Plotting Activity and call if from the background thread. Clips along in real-time just fine. The plots are nice. But I've been told I shouldn't have to use static methods as though there is some problem with that. So what else should I use?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `background thread`. Instead you should use a `Service` that collects the data. In this case every activity you create can bind to that service and be informed if new data was received. With a handler, the service can easily send the data to the activity that is binded.

A little question: Can you please explain why there should be a problem with static methods and more precisely: which kind of problems?

Comment: in my question I stated that this open source code that I am hacking on. It is unlikely that I will change the design but rather extend it. So using a static method is the only thing that extends the design that actually works. As for problems with static methods I don't know. Maybe thread safety?

Comment: You wrote that you have been told that there is a problem. When you work with a handler than everything should be fine...

Comment: I have been told by @CommonsWare to put my pre-exiting background thread/logic into a Service. I don't have the best memory, but I believe that's what he said. So that's what I will be working on. @CommonsWare has 100,000+ reputation, so I am inclined to trust him and take his advice.

Comment: To follow an advice given by CommonsWare is never a bad thing as he as a huge amount of knowledge of android programming. An advice from myself: never trust reputation alone :) They are humans, too, and they can make mistakes :)